# Get row hieght from JQGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I understand I can set the row height of a JQGrid by doing the below.

```
$("#list").jqGrid({

loadComplete: function() {
    var grid = $("#list"),
        ids = grid.getDataIDs();

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        grid.setRowData(ids[i], false, { height : 20 + (i * 2) });
    }
}
});
```

I was just wondering if there a similar method I can use to loop through the grid and “GET” the row height for each row?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the id of the each row - then it is easy to loop and do

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    loadComplete : function() {
        var grid = $("#list"), rowheight={},
        ids = grid.getDataIDs();

        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            rowheight[ids[i]] = $("#"+ ids[i]).height();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @user3580480, Thanks. Glad to help.